# Tables accessed during last period

Tags: postgresql, trigger, timestamp, access-control

I want to check which tables have been updated during a given period, for instance in descending order of access time per table.

How can I get that for PostgreSQL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/5155/1396) question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get some information about the last change to a table with [`xmin`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html), eg:

```
select max(xmin::text::bigint) from t;
```

But you need to be aware [of many caveats](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2009-02/msg01183.php) including [modulo and wraparound](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-WRAPAROUND) and [frozen xids](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-VACUUM-FREEZE-MIN-AGE).

testbed:

```
set role dba;
create role stack;
grant stack to dba;
create schema authorization stack;
set role stack;
--
create or replace function f(p_schema in text, p_table in text) 
                  returns integer language plpgsql immutable as $$
declare
  n integer;
begin
  execute 'select max(xmin::text::bigint) from '||p_schema||'.'||p_table into n;
  return n;
end;$$;
--
create table foo as select generate_series(1, 100) as id;
create table bar as select generate_series(1, 100) as id;
create table baz as select generate_series(1, 100) as id;
--
```

method:

```
select table_name, f(table_schema, table_name)
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema='stack'
order by 2 desc;
/*
 table_name |   f
------------+--------
 baz        | 784657
 bar        | 784656
 foo        | 784655
*/
--
update foo set id=id+1 where id=100;
--
select table_name, f(table_schema, table_name)
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema='stack'
order by 2 desc;
/*
 table_name |   f
------------+--------
 foo        | 784658
 baz        | 784657
 bar        | 784656
*/
```

cleanup:

```
drop schema stack cascade;
set role dba;
drop role stack;
```

Comment: +1 Not perfectly reliable, but very simple and cheap.

Answer (score 2):

A vanilla PostgreSQL installation does not log access to tables.

If you need that you have to implement it yourself. I would use triggers for that. I use a setup like this for many of my tables. I add a column named `log_up` to tables I want to track updates for:

```
log_up timestamptz DEFAULT current_timestamp;
```

Use `timestamptz` (`timestamp with time zone`) which works across time zones:

- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_log_up()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   NEW.log_up := current_timestamp;
   RETURN NEW;
END;
$func$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER log_up
BEFORE UPDATE ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_log_up();
```

There are a couple of related [logging parameters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-logging.html) you may be interested in additionally. Like `log_connections` or `log_statement`.

**Update:**
Also consider ***"commit timestamps"*** added in Postgres **9.5**:

- [Use system timestamp comparison in SELECT query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143305/select-query-with-system-timestamp-comparison/143307?noredirect=1#comment272142_143307)

#### Add trigger to all tables

You can create a script for all currently existing tables by querying the database catalog. For instance to generate the DDL statements for all tables in the schema `public`:

```
SELECT string_agg(format('CREATE TRIGGER log_up BEFORE UPDATE ON %s '
                         'FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_log_up();'
                        , c.oid::regclass), E'\n')
FROM   pg_namespace n
JOIN   pg_class     c ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
WHERE  n.nspname = 'public';
-- AND c.relname ~~* '%tbl%' -- to filter tables by name
```

Returns:

```
CREATE TRIGGER log_up BEFORE UPDATE ON tbl1 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_log_up();
CREATE TRIGGER log_up BEFORE UPDATE ON tbl2 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_log_up();
CREATE TRIGGER log_up BEFORE UPDATE ON tbl3 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_log_up();
...
```

Of course, they all need to have a column `log_up` of type `timestamptz` first. You can create a DDL script to add the column to all tables in a similar fashion.

---

#### Log only last `UPDATE` per table

If you are only interested in the last `UPDATE` per table, a simpler solution will do. Here is a demo how to keep track in one centralized table:

```
CREATE TABLE lastup (
  schema_name text
, tbl_name text
, ts timestamptz
, PRIMARY KEY (schema_name, tbl_name)
);
```

Trigger. Consult the [manual about the special variables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html) I use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_lastup()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   UPDATE lastup
   SET    ts = current_timestamp
   WHERE  schema_name = TG_TABLE_SCHEMA
   AND    tbl_name    = TG_TABLE_NAME;

   RETURN NULL;   -- For AFTER trigger irrelevant
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Dummy table for testing:

```
CREATE TABLE dummy (id int);
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES (1), (2), (3);
```

Enter row for table in log table:

```
INSERT INTO lastup(schema_name, tbl_name) VALUES ('public', 'dummy');
```

Trigger. Note that I use an `AFTER` trigger `FOR EACH STATEMENT` (cheaper). [More in the manual here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html)

```
CREATE TRIGGER log_up
AFTER UPDATE ON dummy
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_lastup();
```

Test:

```
UPDATE dummy
SET    id = id + 5
WHERE  id < 3;
```

Voilá:

```
SELECT * FROM lastup;
```

---

**Or**, if you want to **exclude empty updates** (nothing changed), but at a higher cost because multiple updated rows trigger multiple log updates:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_lastup()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF OLD IS DISTINCT FROM NEW THEN  -- check for changes
      UPDATE lastup
      SET    ts = current_timestamp
      WHERE  schema_name = TG_TABLE_SCHEMA
      AND    tbl_name    = TG_TABLE_NAME;
   END IF;

   RETURN NULL;  -- For AFTER trigger!
END;
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER log_up
AFTER UPDATE ON dummy
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_lastup();  -- per ROW instead of STATEMENT
```

---

To **create triggers** for all tables you want to include in this regime, use a similar DDL creation script like above.

Comment: What if I want to
 `CREATE TRIGGER log_up
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON <<all tables of database>>
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_log_up();`

Comment: But for that I will have to change all the tables of my database, which is not feasible

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: I added another solution for the last update per table.