# How to reuse an update trigger for multiple tables in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, update, audit, metadata

In the database for a new project, I've started the convention of having each table have a last modified timestamp column.  To implement this, I wrote a trigger for each table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER touch_users
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON users
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (OLD.modification_time IS NOT DISTINCT FROM NEW.modification_time)
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE touch_modification_time();

CREATE TRIGGER touch_company
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON company
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (OLD.modification_time IS NOT DISTINCT FROM NEW.modification_time)
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE touch_modification_time();

-- etc for each table
```

This gets tedious fairly quickly; especially since they're exactly the same, except for the table name.

Is there a way I can reduce the boilerplate required for each table?  Or possibly even eliminate it altogether with a single trigger that acts on every table by default?

Comment: Write a small bit of perl (or whatever you fancy) that writes the code for you.

Comment: And why row triggers? Statement level triggers seem to be good for this simple task. And execute a whole procedure? Why? Don't you just want to update the `modification_time` with the current datetime?

Comment: @ypercube - the particular logic in this trigger is to only update modification_time if it omitted; e.g. allow it to be explicitly updated if desired.  I'm not an sql guru; I'm not familiar with statement triggers.

Comment: @ypercube How would a statement trigger be useful here? It's inherently per-row, and has to alter the `NEW` tuple in the `BEFORE` phase.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Aren't statement triggers more efficient than row triggers?

Comment: @ypercube: It's only speculation as long as we don't see the trigger function itself. But most probably the intention is to change the modification time of *each row*. That requires `FOR EACH ROW`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Right, I assumed/speculated they wanted something as simple as setting `NEW.time = now`

Comment: @ypercube: a statement-level trigger with postgres cannot do `new.time=now`. Quoting the doc: _For row-level INSERT and UPDATE triggers **only**, the returned row becomes the row that will be inserted or will replace_...

Comment: @DanielVérité I don't understand what that quote has to do with my comments. But I reread the whole chapters in Postgres documentation about triggers and i found that **"PostgreSQL does not allow the old and new tables to be referenced in statement-level triggers, i.e., the tables that contain all the old and/or new rows, which are referred to by the OLD TABLE and NEW TABLE clauses in the SQL standard."** Which clears my confusion about what can and not be done with statement triggers.

Comment: @ypercube: The quote is from the [`CREATE TRIGGER` page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html).
The chapter [Overview of Trigger Behavior](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/trigger-definition.html) has a more detailed assessment.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thnx. Do I understand correctly that currently statement level triggers are pretty limited and not of much use?

Comment: @ypercube: You do. I rarely use them. Only good for special cases.

Comment: [So do you have your answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/169168)

Answer (score 4):

Single trigger function for multiple triggers: possible - that's what you do.
Single trigger for multiple tables: *not* possible.

But you can shorten the code for creating lots of triggers:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN

EXECUTE (
SELECT string_agg('CREATE TRIGGER touch_users
   BEFORE UPDATE ON ' || quote_ident(t) || '
   FOR EACH ROW
   WHEN (OLD.modification_time IS NOT DISTINCT FROM NEW.modification_time)
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE touch_modification_time();'
 , E'\n')
FROM unnest('{users, company, foo, bar}'::text[]) t -- list your tables here
);

END
$$;
```

Or gather table names from system catalogs:
[Tables accessed during last period](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12374/tables-accessed-during-last-periods-in-postgresql/12378#12378)