# Use system timestamp comparison in SELECT query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, timestamp

I have to backup some tables on a daily basis using the condition that the backup will be only for one previous day. I am planning to use `copy` to dump the records in to a csv file. I need help in getting my query correct, below is the query I am using but does not seem to work:

```
psql -d my_db -c 'copy (select * from mytab WHERE date_trunc('day',NOW() - interval '1 day') TO STDOUT' -o data1.copy;
```

Answer (score 3):

The `WHERE` expression does not make sense:

```
WHERE date_trunc('day',NOW() - interval '1 day'
```

It has to evaluate to a `boolean` value and you need to compare to an actual column of the table like (assuming a `timestamp` , `timestamptz` or `date` column):

```
WHERE my_timestamp_column >= (NOW()::date - 1)
AND   my_timestamp_column <   NOW()::date
```

Postgres does not store a creation timestamp for table rows automatically. You need to add a column yourself to keep track (with default value and / or a trigger to make sure). Detailed instructions with code in this related answer:

- [Tables accessed during last period](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12374/tables-accessed-during-last-periods-in-postgresql/12378#12378)

#### "Commit timestamps" in Postgres **9.5** or later

You can activate the [`track_commit_timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-replication.html#GUC-TRACK-COMMIT-TIMESTAMP) setting to start tracking. Then you can use [`pg_xact_commit_timestamp(xmin)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-COMMIT-TIMESTAMP) to retrieve the timestamp when each row was inserted or updated (after you started tracking). To get all rows that were inserted or updated within the last day:

```
SELECT * FROM mytab 
WHERE  pg_xact_commit_timestamp(xmin) > now() - interval '1 day'
```

Certain limitations apply. Commit timestamps are not kept indefinitely. Read the [Postgres Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#Commit_timestamp_tracking) for details.

Once activated, commit timestamps are tracked for *all* transactions in the DB cluster, which causes a performance hit. If you only need it for one or a few tables, rather add timestamps to involved table(s) manually like instructed above.

Comment: Hi Erwin, there is no TS field in some of my tables. I need to backup such tables as well, I was hoping there could be a where clause that can take the unix timestmp (remember doing something like this is mysql long time back). Do you have any logic in such a case, thanks for helping out

Comment: @user2709587: Consider added information.